# Today reputation count showing wrong after 11PM EST

Tags: support, reputation

Just before 11PM EST I saw today reputation count as 135, but around 11:40EST I am seeing my today reputation count as 2. Is this because of any timezone related to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are not confusing the times?  Looking at your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094597/thinksteep?tab=reputation), you earned 132 reputation yesterday, and 2 today (though you earned more around the time you posted here).

Stack Exchange runs on UTC time.  The UTC day switches over at 7pm EST.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?

Comment: @soandos I had misread it as an AM/PM issue at first, you're right.  I did a bit more looking and added a bit more detail - day switchover still seems right to me.

Comment: @Rebecca: Now it make sense. Thanks.